# Android programming remote control using IR

Tags: android, infrared

I am trying to develop app for remote control of video projectors using Infrared (IR). 
I found the documentation for android.hardware.ConsumerIrManager but it is supported only for API 19 (Android 4.4) and up.

Is there some other way (API) for using the IR and transmiting IR codes which support older Android versions ex. 4.x.x ?

Comment: Have you checked the support libraries to see if it is in?

Comment: The library is included in the support libraries and I can import it successfully. When i write  ConsumerIrManager mCIR = (ConsumerIrManager)getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);
i get error message: Field requires API Level 19 (current min is 8)

Comment: I guess all you can do is disable the feature for any device lower than API level 19 then. Unless there's a good third party library.

Comment: I think Android devices before API level 19 had to use OEM-specific APIs. So, if it was HTC you had to use HTC's library.

Comment: Yes @Dwebtron you are right. After thorough exploration I found that there is no way to use infrared on devices before API level 19. HTC had their own library and they have released it for the public, and Samsung also have their own API but it's not released for the public. I didn't find any other manufacturer to have any kind of IR API. So we are pretty much limited.